# top primary menu drop down categories not showing

Tags: dropdown, theme-twenty-fourteen

recently my drop down categories have started to not show on mobile devices once clicked. they seem to go straight to the actual page titled and not show my drop down categories. (mikesnature.com) they used to work but now don't, is their anything I can do to fix this?

Mike

Comment: This seems to be a javascript problem , please provide more information , check your browser's console for any errors, especially when clicking on the navigation link or button

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer, but you have a Javascript error.

```
// listen for postMessage events from the notifications iframe
$( window ).on( 'message', function( e ) {
    var event = ! e.data && e.originalEvent.data ? e.originalEvent : event;
    if ( event.origin !== 'https://widgets.wp.com' ) {
        return;
    }

    var data = ( 'string' === typeof event.data ) ? parseJson( event.data, {} ) : event.data;
    if ( 'notesIframeMessage' !== data.type ) {
        return;
    }

    var eventData = notesTracksEvents[ data.action ];
    if ( ! eventData ) {
        return;
    }

    recordTracksEvent( eventData( data ) );
} );
```

It's erroring out on this line specifically (`event.origin` is not defined), so it looks like `event` is not always an actual event. You should have some type-checking in place. I think this is probably happening before your menu JS kicks in, so it's not actually running properly.

```
if ( event.origin !== 'https://widgets.wp.com' ) {
```